# System.Drawing.Image 'Parameter is not valid' when image source is from Android

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly, system.drawing

I am developing a Blazor WASM app to interface with the backend of a winforms application. Images in this winforms application are loaded with `System.Drawing.Image.FromStream()`.

Images that are uploaded from my web app are working correctly when done from my computer; but if I use my Android phone, then System.Drawing.Image gives me the `Parameter is not valid` exception when loading from the stream. Unfortunately, I don't have any other devices to attempt from. Both devices used Chrome browser.

- I have dumped the stream to a file to ensure that the stream is not broken, which works as expected.
- I have tried with `validateImageData` set to false

I have a small reproducible snippet using the `System.Drawing.Common` nuget package for asp core:

index.razor

```cs
<InputFile OnChange="@OnInputFileChange" />

@code {
    private async Task OnInputFileChange(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        var fileContent = new StreamContent(e.File.OpenReadStream());
        using var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        content.Add(
            content: fileContent,
            name: "\"files\"",
            fileName: e.File.Name);
        var response = await Http.PostAsync("/WeatherForecast/save", content);
    }
}
```

Controller

```cs
[HttpPost("save")]
public async Task Save([FromForm] IEnumerable<IFormFile> files)
{
    var file = files.First();
    //throws exception if source comes from Android
    Image img = Image.FromStream(file.OpenReadStream());
}
```

What is Android doing to the images to break System.Drawing.Image? What am I missing?

##### Edit:

After some more testing I have observed that there are other details that contribute to this exception being triggered. If the actual picture source is from somewhere say a download from Reddit, then the exception will occur, but if it is a picture taken from the phone itself it does not occur. Both images on my phone are being reported as a `.jpg`, but unfortunately, I just don't know enough about how images work under the hood to navigate my way through this problem.

Comment: Unfortunately copying to a MemoryStream does not make a difference. And I am as sure as I can be that I'm uploading the same file type, in the actual application the image is uploaded to an Azure storage server before the winforms application runs `Image.FromStream()` and I can verify that all the details are correct and that the image is whole.

Comment: I would love to drop System.Drawing in the winforms app, but I definitely have to run that past the team since my current focus is the web side of things. That may honestly be the only solution, but I had to try everything before I suggest such a drastic change.

Comment: I am also aware of the caveats of System.Drawing.Common; I only used it for my very small test project to quickly test various changes since the behavior was the same.